# Roll function for chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Would a roll function for our excellent chat site help this site be a success?  Would you use it?

Answer (score 2):

I think having a chat bot that does it is sufficient. If I'm using it to game with a bunch of friends, I expect them to be honest. If I'm using it as a joke, or just to mess around, I don't really care about the fairness of it.

There is currently a chat bot in "The Game Table" chat room; however, it's kind of broken (try typing "8d6" in chat, and see what it produces. It would be nice to see it fixed, but I don't consider it a critical feature of the site.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, it works for me [here](http://chat.rpg.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2521#2521)

Comment: For "8d6" it gave me a block of blank text about 10-12 lines long, which had like a bullet point icon on the left side of each line.

Comment: Now it seems like it's working, and I see dice icons

Comment: 8d6 works for me, too.  Except, my first roll *sucked*!  Three ones and two twos, really?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are plenty of options for folks out there that need dice rollers.  I don't think I'd like to see this feature here.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [reported death of Google Wave](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/update-on-google-wave.html), my group has been looking for a replacement for play-by-post. We might end up hosting [Wave in a Box](http://googlewavedev.blogspot.com/2010/09/wave-open-source-next-steps-wave-in-box.html) somewhere, but certainly I would consider running games on the RPG Stack Exchange chat. Keeping it PG might be a challenge, though, since my games tend to delve into "violence, horror and adult themes."

The Dice Service bot in the Game Table would meet my needs, but whether the community would actually *want* me creating a chat room (or two) for my own play-by-post game is a [separate issue](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/viability-of-a-chat-based-game).

Comment: We've now got a couple chat rooms devoted to a chat-based game, but we're strongly relying on Wave and other resources for a lot of the background action in the game.  I suggest checking out Epic Words and iPlay4e.