# Viability of a chat based game?

Tags: discussion, chat

Would it be appropriate and useful for the site for me/someone else to run games via the chat area? I'm thinking fairly slow paced, one for D&D encounters style and one for indie games.

Edit

Sorry, need to clarify my question. Is not "Is anyone interested" But "Is it good for the site to have this?" My default expectation is, considering the audience, I'd be able to find 3-4 people who are interested (or play around with some more... obscure ideas, like group characters) But yes, I'm considering if it's appropriate and good for the site.

Comment: [Conversation about it in chat](http://chat.rpg.stackexchange.com/rooms/3/conversation/chat-game-discussion-2010-1015).

Comment: The point was raised that such games would have to be PG-13 or cleaner.

Comment: If and when you get up to running something, please contact the mods.  I'd like one of us to be on during the first game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the few weeks it's been running, I think we've got a good idea of how well (or not well) the "chat-based" game is functioning.

As for the game being anything we could call "chat-based", I would say it's a hard failure.  Hardly anything aside from "table talk" is actually being done in the chat.  Everything else has either been done from the start in Google Docs, Wave, or other web resources, or has been moved over to those resources out of necessity.  Having a chat room available for expediting conversations when there is more than one person from the group online at once is definitely a bonus.  However, I would say that overall the chat is playing a very minor - and mostly replaceable - part in the game.

However, what this question has spawned is (I think) something that can become a great asset to the community.  That is, the idea of an online game for play-testing Answers from the site.  I definitely look forward to seeing what can come out of this exercise in that regard, and would love to see more groups popping up and doing this.

So, a reminder to everyone:  Just because there is one play-testing game in progress doesn't mean that it has to be the only one.  Feel free to start your own and recruit some players!

Comment: Is that an imposed, or chosen restriction?

Comment: I have a strong feeling it's imposed.  I'll see about finding a source for that.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it would be great. I would definitely be interested in playing via chat.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt I would play much, but I would be interested in observing other's exploits.

Answer (score 0):

(This post made community wiki, so people can just edit the [expletive] out of this idea)

Assuming that people think that the game is viable, here's my proposition for the first one, inspired by group chess and the design of the site.

The rough intent is to create a game where a number of questions currently pending on the site can be explored. I'll run a very light but crunchy game (PG... won't mention blood). The trick is, once the characters are created, no-one will have ownership of them. Rather, as combat rounds go by once a day, people who respond will decide characters actions, with no one person deciding more than one action. Mods, of course, can have "real" characters if desired, or co-gming spots as necessary.

Thus, we can test out various answers from the main forum and provide a way for new people to participate.

Is this a horrible idea? My inner GM is screaming at me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You are going to post a question for what each character should do each day?

Comment: Roughly speaking, though I won't be using the formal question mechanism. Just polling responses in chat. The big problem is keeping participation up and having daily rounds is bad enough.

Comment: If it's possible to have a "reputationless" venue, I'd consider doing it through questions, but it would be a horrible gaming of the system otherwise (though an /absolutely/ fascinating way of creating character actions. Can you think of how that would have helped in the PAX celeb game?)